# Call GET services again whenever the localization of website changes Angular 4/5

Tags: angular, single-page-application, angular5

How To Call GET services again whenever the localization of website changes without page reload? The website is SPA and developed in angular 5. The package I am using is http://www.ngx-translate.com/

Comment: ummm what's the question here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need :

```
localization = navigator.language;

setInterval(() => {
    if(this.localization !== navigator.language) {
        // call your get method
    }
},1000);
```

You can change time Interval as per your requirement.